# Install make, gcc and similar on fresh Debian install without internet connection

Tags: debian

I'm a long time Fedora BFU and decided to switch to Debian for my new Dell XPS. Unfortunately, on a fresh install, I only get to work with a microscopic CLI and no internet connection, as both GPU and network card seem to need additional drivers to work. I found both drivers online, but I'm failing to install them.

GPU driver needs `cc` in $PATH, but I think I'm missing GCC alltogether:

```bsh
gcc # command not found, 
man gcc # no manual entry for gcc
```

With Realtek, I cannot make the installer: `make # make: command not found`

I'm a bit surprised that I don't get `gcc` and `make` out of the box - is there an easy way to install some bundle multiple of these basic apps from a USB drive?

Comment: try this (although the question is about MX linux, that just seems to be a variant of old debian, so the answer applies to your debian): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654020/installing-packages-from-usb-to-offline-mx-linux-system/654037#654037

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ways to update Ubuntu (debian-based distros) offline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89152/ways-to-update-ubuntu-debian-based-distros-offline)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [installing packages from USB to offline MX Linux system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654020/installing-packages-from-usb-to-offline-mx-linux-system)

Comment: Using another connection, download the packages to USB and use dpkg -i somename.deb  Within recent years downstream distributions broke Network Manager and this was the solution at the time. Note the dependencies such as gpp too.

Comment: Just USB-tether via your smartphone, and then install the needed packages to get the onboard network card working. Or is there a detail in your situation, that makes this impossible? If so, please edit it into your question.

Comment: @AlexStragies Unfortunately I don't have an appropriate cable - laptop only has USB-C and my smartphone uses microusb... but wouldn't that still fail without network card drivers?

Comment: All major OSs have had drivers for USB network tethering with standard smartphones since many years. Just pick up a USBC-to-microUSB adapter for a few pennies. That'll also reduce the number of cables you need to lug around. And you can probably avoid compiling things if you just install the 5.1X kernel from debian backports

Comment: @AlexStragies Yeah, you're right. I'll get a chance to buy the cable on thursday, I will do that. I managed to solve the issue with help from Stephen Kitt btw (although other arose).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your situation, I would install using [the unofficial, firmware-included full DVD](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/10.10.0+nonfree/amd64/iso-dvd/) (which can also be used on a USB stick). While labelled as “unofficial” this is still prepared by the same people who prepare the official installation images, and it has two advantages in your specific use-case:

- it includes firmware and non-free drivers, possibly including those you need for your hardware;
- it also includes GCC, Make etc., so you can install them directly.

GCC and Make aren’t installed by default; to install them from the installation image, ensure your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file still has the

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.10.0 _Buster_ - Unofficial amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20210619-16:16]/ buster contrib main non-free
```

entry (as set up by the installer — the exact timestamp might vary), mount the DVD image, and run

```
apt install gcc make
```

as root.

(If you want to give Debian 11 a shot, [the equivalent image is also available](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/bullseye_di_rc2+nonfree/amd64/iso-dvd/), using RC2 of the installer. This has a newer kernel than the Debian 10 setup, and may work better on your new hardware.)

If you don’t need non-free firmware, but would like to be able to install GCC and Make from the installation media rather than from Internet mirrors, you can use [the official DVD images](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/release/current/amd64/iso-dvd/) instead (only the first DVD is needed).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126775/discussion-between-mkurz-and-stephen-kitt).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this without restarting, without grinding for help or etc. and it works for others! I tested it and it works!
To install `make` and `cmake`, use: (only onto /home/(user)

```
mkdir bin
```

And enter to bin using `cd bin`
Then on what you'll do is:

```
apt-get download make
```

This will download make and next is:

```
dpkg-deb -x make_(version)_(cpu_insturtructure_idk_what_to_call_it).deb /home/(user)/bin
```

This will extract whatever is on here

**WARNING** this may get complicated for sh or bash users so for sh:`nano ~/.bashsrc` and bash: `nano ~/.bashrc` and go the bottom and modify at the end.

So for me, I would personally recommend you using bash not sh cause my pc is on sh, you can use the command `bash` to enter to bash.

We gotta edit the .bashrc file so we need to enter:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

It is non-root so it will work then we gotta add this at the end:

```
export PATH="/home/(user)/bin/make_(version)_(cpu_insturtructure_idk_what_to_call_it)/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

Then save it.

When you're done, you can execute this command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

And voilà! It will work easily!

You can also do that with gcc BUT in a separate file if you could find the bin file under usr file.

Comment: How does that work without an Internet connection?

Comment: If you downloaded using the apt-get download command

Comment: Again, how do you do that without an Internet connection? (That’s the whole point of the question...)

Comment: Put another way, if the OP had already downloaded the packages with `apt-get download`, they could just have installed them.

Comment: Correct but IF the OP or sudo can do that or if already downloaded

Comment: You’re still not addressing the “without Internet connection” part of the question. Also, while your approach works (mostly) for `make`, it won’t work for `gcc`.

Comment: cause gcc is also not installed and it is seperated and it needs to get it installed